# list of lists in alphabteical order with python

Tags: python, list

How would I sort a list of list in alphabetical order in python?

```
Class1_Scores = [['Meg'], 10, ['James'], 12, ['Mark'], 11]
for x in sorted(Class1_Scores[0]+1):
    print(x)
```

Every time I run this code it says "TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list"

Comment: Your code's wrong, it's not a list of lists.

Comment: What is `+1` supposed to do?

Comment: I only want to output the strings in alphabetical order

Comment: Add the expected output

Comment: I was unsure how to make a list of lists

Comment: ['Meg', 10]
['James', 12]
['Mark', 11]

Comment: @Shard, `a=[[12,34,21],[1,2,3,4]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want something like this:

```
Class1_Scores = [['Meg', 10], ['James', 12], ['Mark', 11]]
for x in sorted(Class1_Scores):
    print(x[0])
```

Output:

```
James
Mark
Meg
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is trying to `concatenate` or `add` the `list type` variable with `integer` variable. This is not allowed.

```
>>> Class1_Scores = [['Meg'], 10, ['James'], 12, ['Mark'], 11]
>>> Class1_Scores[0]
['Meg']
>>> type(Class1_Scores[0])
<type 'list'>
>>> type(1)
<type 'int'>
>>> Class1_Scores[0]+1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "int") to list
>>>
```

---

Use `Pythonic` way to get Names from the list of list:-

```
>>> sorted([i[0] for i in Class1_Scores if isinstance(i, list)])
['James', 'Mark', 'Meg']


>>> Class1_Scores = [['Meg', 10], ['James', 12], ['Mark', 11]]
>>> sorted([i[0] for i in Class1_Scores])
['James', 'Mark', 'Meg']
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll use this

Comment: Welcome. free to ask any issue on stackoverflow or I can be reached anytime via email at vivekbsable@gmail.com, for my skype id: vivek.igp.